# Using SMTP Relay on a Exim Server in VPS for Multiple Domains

Tags: email, smtp, exim

I am moving my email behind a dynamic IP, and I will need to SMTP relay outbound email in order to avoid spam lists.

My domain is hosted through a BlueHost VPS running EXIM. I am wondering what I would have to configure to run two domains outbound through my one VPS using SMTP Relay and have me email not be market for spam.

If I do relay through my VPS, will I be able to do so with multiple domains? For instance, thedilldesign.com and virginiaseo.org are both my domains/companies. thedilldesign.com is hosted on my VPS, though the domain is registered through GoDaddy and DNS is held by CloudFlare. Would I be able to send email using thedilldesign.com domain name from my dynamic IP address and relay through my static IP on my VPS? Would these outbound emails have an appropriate reverse SMTP banner and RDNS so that I am not flagged as spam? Would I have to configure thedilldesign.com to be on its own static IP with its own mailserver, or can it share the relay capabilities with the other domain off of the same IP?

Any information on multiple domains through a VPS SMTP Relay is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

DNS settings:

1. set up so-called `reverse record` that bind your IP-address with some domain, f.e.  `thedilldesign.com`. Usually you can do it via VPS management panel
2. set MX records for all your domains to the same value - `thedilldesign.com`
3. set SPF records for all your domains to confirm that `thedilldesign.com` is legal submitter for that domains

EXIM settings

3. set `local_domains = virginiaseo.org : thedilldesign.com`
4. set up TLS / certificates. You can use selfsigned certs for free
5. set up authentication over TLS and allow only autenticated users to send messages outbound.

Email software

6. set up SMTPS/IMAPS connections to the server, confirm selfsigned certs.

This steps guarantee that you can send emails from any location/connection via encrypted tunnel, and all your messages will be accepted by recipients as far as your server has valid plain and reverse DNS-records and proper SPF-records.

Comment: All good recommendations, but I wouldn't say "steps guarantee...all your messages will be accepted". If he's sending spam, it will (eventually start to) get rejected, even if it's coming from a known good source. Modern mail systems use sender (domain and IP) reputation as much as spam score to determine whether to accept an email. The main factors affecting him: is he sending personal correspondence (one to one) or is he sending out bulk email? If he's sending bulk, he's also liable to ruin the good reputation of his current mail server that he plans to smarthost through.

Comment: I mean that no messages will be rejected because of wrong reverse record or email domain and MTA domain mismatching. Any other reasons are possible and probable.

Comment: Yeah, he really didn't give enough detail about his intent and the content to know for sure.  But anyway I wanted to say that your answers are (and always are) very good.